# spring cloud gateway authorize all request by keycloak token but need avoiding auth endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I wrote a gateway service using spring-cloud-starter-gateway. Also, I put Keycloak settings on the service so that all endpoints are validated with tokens. The problem I have is that token checking should not be done for services ending in /auth-service/**.
this is keycloak setting in application.yml:

```
   spring:
     cloud:
      gateway:
        routes:
          - id: customer-service
            uri: http://127.0.0.1:8090/
            predicates:
              - Path=/customer-service/v1.0/**
            filters:
              - RewritePath=/scustomer-service/v1.0/(?<path>.*),/customer-service/v1.0/$\{path}

          - id: order-service
            uri: http://127.0.0.1:8086/
            predicates:
              - Path=/order-service/v1.0/**
            filters:
              - RewritePath=/order-service/v1.0/(?<path>.*),/order-service/v1.0/$\{path}

           - id: auth-service
             uri: http://127.0.0.1:8085/
             predicates:
               - Path=/auth-service/v1.0/**
             filters:
               - RewritePath=/auth-service/v1.0/(?<path>.*),/auth-service/v1.0/$\{path}

     security:
       oauth2:
        client:
          registration:
            keycloak:
            client-id: login-app
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid

          provider:
            keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9002/auth/realms/test-app
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username

       resourceserver:
         jwt:
           issuer-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9002/auth/realms/test-app
```

the gradle dependencies is:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
implementation 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.5.2'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.4'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

}

and this is the security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth-service/**"))).
            csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth-service/**")).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/swagger-ui/**")).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()).csrf().disable().httpBasic(withDefaults());

    
    http.csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
}


@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverterForKeycloak() {
    Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwt -> {
        Map<String, Object> resourceAccess = jwt.getClaim("resource_access");

        Object client = resourceAccess.get("login-app");

        LinkedTreeMap<String, List<String>> clientRoleMap = (LinkedTreeMap<String, List<String>>) client;

        List<String> clientRoles = new ArrayList<>(clientRoleMap.get("roles"));

        return clientRoles.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    };

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();

    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);

    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}
```

}

every thins is ok and all endpoint secured and checked by token. the problem is when user can try to get token using post request 127.0.0.1:8080/auth-service/token. this is needs token and raise error "An expected CSRF token cannot be found".

Comment: You might find this [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) (when using `oauth2Login` with a browser, **requests are authorized with session cookie**, not tokens in `Authorization` header, and your `JwtAuthenticationConverter` will never be called) and [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) useful.